# Can't access WordPress site in subfolder

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, subdirectory

everyone!

I have 2 WordPress websites. One in ROOT and the other one in a subfolder MYSUBFOLDER.

```
/
/mysubfolder/
```

And I can't navigate through the subfolder website. Everytime I try, it redirects me to the root website with a 404 page.

I noticed after changing my subfolder .htaccess file, I can access any page correctly, but, then, it changes by itself again to the wrong code.

Correct code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysubfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysubfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

After navigating, it changes to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: try to not RewriteBase

RewriteBase /
but rewrite tule

RewriteRule . /mysubfolder/index.php [L]

Comment: Hello, @Dreamm, the problem is not related to .htaccess code, but the automatic rewriting... I don't know how to stop it.

Comment: siteUrl option on database?

i have test server and prod. 
my test server in subfolder and "siteurl" & "home" records on database in table prefix_options set like Http://test.server/mysubfolder  and all fine

Comment: Hi, @Dreamm, "siteurl" and "home" fields are correct in both websites :/

Comment: 1. The database reference of the subfolder directory are correct?
2. if you  rename the htaccess of the root site you see the subfolder site?

Comment: @Dreamm, I just updated both WordPress versions and it seems to be working fine now! :) Anyway, thank you so much for the help, friend!

Comment: cheers, glad to read this :)